# How to create primary key using multiple columns & Auto increment id?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, composite-primary-key

This is my tables structures

```
mysql> DESCRIBE sections;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sec_id   | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sec_name | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sec_type | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE subjects;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| sub_id          | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sub_name        | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sections_sec_id | int(5)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE chapters;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| chp_id          | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| chp_name        | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subjects_sub_id | int(5)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sections_sec_id | int(5)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE questions;
+-----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| que_id          | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| que_text        | text      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| que_created     | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| chapters_chp_id | int(5)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subjects_sub_id | int(5)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sections_sec_id | int(5)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> DESCRIBE answers;
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ans_id           | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ans_text         | text      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ans_created      | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| questions_que_id | int(11)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| chapters_chp_id  | int(5)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subjects_sub_id  | int(5)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sections_sec_id  | int(5)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Let's assume 'Answers' table**

I created the '**ans_id**' as the primary key of '**Answers**' table, created a another **UNIQUE** key using ***(ans_id,questions_que_id,chapters_chp_id,subjects_sub_id,sections_sec_id)***

[image: This how i created UNIQUE key using mysql workbench]

**What i want do.**

create primary key for 'Answers' table using (ans_id,questions_que_id,chapters_chp_id,subjects_sub_id,sections_sec_id) columns and create **Trigger before INSERT** to create 'auto_increment' id.

Finally i want to accomplish this

[image: I want to do like this]

Comment: Why? If you have an auto-increment - why do you need to put additional stuff into the primary key? Composite keys are used if it makes sense and then you don't use an identity value. It seems to me you just should let your id be the primary key and then make proper indexes over the other columns

Comment: I agree with Allan, and Also, to complete his question - Why do you keep sections_sec_id in every table? it's enough to keep it in the subjects table. the chapters table should not contain sections_sec_id as it is derived from the subjects table. this is also true for sections_sec_id and subjects_sub_id in table questions, and for chapters_chp_id, subjects_sub_id and sections_sec_id in table answers.

Comment: I don't know why someone gave you a positive vote. What you want to do is nonsense.

Comment: Dear @AllanS.Hansen, Zohar Peled my supervisor asked me to do that. Already I have developed my system in the way you mention. I have edited my question. I have added screenshot of answer table. can u refer that?

Comment: @medina you are probably correct but there are situations that you might want to keep such structure. I agree it probably makes not sense in this case, but if - for example - an answer can belong to a different chapter then the chapter of the question it's related to (and I've seen things like that in the past, not answers and questions but still), then it would make perfect sense to have a field to specify the chapter in both answers table and questions table. This is probably not the case here, as implied by the names of the tables, but nevertheless it is a valid structure sometimes.

Comment: @SurajMalinga sometimes supervisors can say dumb things... I'm not really a MySql guy, I do most of my work with mssql, so I can't really advise you how to achieve your goal,  but I do advise you to try to make sense of it. If you have an identity field, then by definition it has unique values, so any other field you may want to add to it for creating a primary key (or any unique index for that matter) is redundant and you would be better off without it. Tell your supervisor that he is wrong and explain why, or ask for clarification as to why he wants to have this database design.
Good luck.

Comment: To add to this discussion, keep the single auto-increment column as primary key and create a unique constraint around the others if that's all you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Phil it's mean the way which i have done is correct? Without creating primary key using multiple column instead of crate 1 primary key for each table and create UNIQUE index with primary key + other foreign keys.

Comment: Creating a unique index involving the primary key is redundant, I've already addressed that issue 32 minutes ago. @Phil, creating a unique index on the other fields will mean that for every question there an be only one answer. I don't thing that this is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Definition: *Primary key is **minimal** set of attributes needed to determine every row in a table*.

UNIQUE index should be {questions_que_id} + {chapters_chp_id} + {subjects_sub_id} +{sections_sec_id} and make sure it is combined as one index with these 4 columns, if you set it as different 4 indexes than you will probably achieve undesired outcome, as Zohar already pointed. From my experience, it could be unpractical to use composite keys like this. For basic table operations (CRUD) you will have to provide a lot of parameters.

Maybe to try this way: autoincremental numeric id as a primary key, the rest of important attributes as UNIQUE index. Then you could count already inserted answers to make sure right number will be assigned to ans_id. Hint: it's maybe easier to achive this from your application layer, not as a trigger or procedure for MySQL. If your users will provide answers as step-by-step, then just save a timestamp and you will know which answer is older so you don't need ans_id at all.